# How to call specific namespace's function in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

Currently I have two function from the same library that could both be called in my situation. How do I specify the specific namespace of the function so that it is called.

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseContentRoot(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder, string)' 
>   and 
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsWebHostBuilderExtensions.UseContentRoot(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder, string)'

That is the error( a bit messy to read ) but that is the problem.

Here is the code:

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;     
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new  WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) //The Problem!!
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to import both namespaces?

Comment: It automatically imports them when using the library. Also this is autogenerated code from AspnetCore. I made no edits haha...

Comment: Are you sure you need `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder` though? It's not needed in my setup.

Comment: I'm now wondering if you have upgraded your project from RC2 to RTM, was that the case? If so, try looking at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5884).

Comment: That is also the specific issue with the calls being ambiguous. I wanted to try and fix it without dealing with Nuget  =( but I think I have to.

Comment: I'd certainly recommend fixing the root cause rather than the symptoms, otherwise something it will likely return in the future to shoot you in the foot!

Comment: I fixed it =) a lot of seemingly wasted time but you are right. No more issues with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a fluent notation, (successive calls to methods chained together), and relying on static extension methods along the way, all of which is nice style.  Not sure how to preserve that nice style, but if you pull it apart, you can target the method call you want, via namespace.

```
 var intermediateResult = new  WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel();
```

Now choose which method you want (my example uses the method from the first namespace, but it's your choice).

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseContentRoot(intermediateResult, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

Ugly, but it should compile, and, presumably, run.

---

**Note**. You'll notice that I called the method `UseContentRoot()` with two  parameters!  That's merely making explicit what is going on underneath.

Static extension methods are written with an initial parameter representing the class for which the method is going to serve as an extension method.  So `UseContentRoot(String currentDir)` is actually written something like `UseContentRoot(this IWebHostBuilder builder, String currentDir)`, meaning that `UseContentRoot` is an extension method being written for class (interface) `IWebHostBuilder`.

The special `this` keyword usage now allows the method to be called (and chained in your case) as though the method were a member of IWebHostBuilder, so that if you have a `IWebHostBuilder builder`, you can do `builder.UseContentRoot(currentDir)`.  So the initial parameter "moves" to the left of the dot and it looks like this extension method is declared on a `IWebHostBuilder` as a method taking one parameter.

But calling it as though it were a method belonging to a `IWebHostBuilder` is just a convenience. You can still call the method as it was originally written, with both of its declared parameters: `UseContentRoot(IWebHostBuilder builder, String currentDir)`, which is how it is actually declared.

Comment: Thank you! I really like your response. Very thorough! And it works haha.